# No funciona relación Muchos a Muchos, Laravel, Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

El problema es que mi código no reconoce la tabla Pivote. 
Tengo tres tablas
Users
Clients
Client_user

Y quiero insertar un usuario nuevo, donde también se debe realizar una inserción en la tabla client_user, con el id de usuario y cliente(ya creado).

Esto es lo que tengo

users.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Users extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $table ='Users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = [
        'username','firstname','lastname','phone', 'email', 'password','url_photo','status'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];


    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Client','client_user','user_id','client_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

}
```

Client.php

```
   protected $table ='clients';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable = ['name'];


    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Users','client_user','user_id','client_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

userController.php

```
public function store(Request $request) {

    $rules=[
        'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname'=> 'required',
        'phone'=> '',
        'email'=> 'required|unique:users,email',
        'password'=>'required',
        'url_photo'=> '',
        'status'=> '',
        'client_id'=> 'required'
     ];

     $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

      if ($validator->fails()) {
         return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);
      } 
      else{

        $user = Users::create([
            'username' =>$request->username,
            'firstname' =>$request->firstname,
            'lastname'=>$request->lastname,
            'phone'=>$request->phone,
            'email'=>$request->email,
            'password'=> Hash::make($request->password),
            'url_photo'=>$request->url_photo,
            'status'=>$request->status
        ]);

        $user->client()->create([
            'client_id' =>$request->client_id
        ]);         

       return response()->json($user->id,200);
        }

}
```

Este es el error

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `clients` ..Connection.php on line 669

Está haciendo un insert en la tabla Client, pero debe ser en Client_user

Muchas gracias,

Comment: Si el Cliente ya existe no uses el método create. Usa attach o sync para relacionarlo https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Funcionó!!, mil gracias